# How do I activate the split theme in beamer?

Tags: beamer

I'd like to have the author and the title in the same line in the footline in beamer. Doing

```
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[split theme]
```

doesn't make any difference.

This did the trick:

```
\usepackage{beamerouterthemesplit}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[split theme]
```

Is this the official solution?

Minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{beamerouterthemesplit}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[split theme]
\title{TITLE}
\author{AUTHOR}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}\frametitle{Foo}bar\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7):

Load it this way:

```
\useoutertheme{split}
```

- `\usetheme[options]{name}` installs the desired presentation theme
- `\useoutertheme[options]{name}` does the same but only for outer themes

Similarly, there are `\useinnertheme`, `\usecolortheme`, and `\usefonttheme`. This is described in the `beamer` user guide in *15.1 Five Flavors of Themes*.

If you only would like to have the footline part of the split theme, you can copy the relevant definition from `beamerouterthemesplit.sty` to your preamble:

```
\defbeamertemplate*{footline}{split theme}
{%
  \leavevmode%
  \hbox{\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,leftskip=.3cm plus1fill,rightskip=.3cm]{author in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\insertshortauthor
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm plus1fil]{title in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle
  \end{beamercolorbox}}%
  \vskip0pt%
}
```

Comment: This does too many changes. I want to change only the footline.

Comment: @pts: You asked for the official solution ;-) I extended my answer to use just the split footline.

Comment: Thank you for the lots of helpful information in your answer.

Comment: @StefanKottwitz sorry to bring back this answer, but when I tried the above, I got `Command \beamer@@tmpop@footline@split theme already defined.` error. Anything I've missed?